# How to get enough watts for Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, fan, desktop-computer

I have a Pre-built computer it's the Phantom 410 case with AMD-FX 6300 prossesor,
but the power supply is only 150 watt. I want to add a fan, but I can't buy a new power supply, so how do I use power case fans in the case without using my power supply?
I didn't try anything but I'm asking this question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27423/discussion-on-question-by-jer-how-to-get-enough-watts-for-power-supply).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is difficult to understand (Not sure what "I cant try anything" means).

Most computer fans will run at 12 volts (nominally), so if you get a fan, and can find another 12 volt power supply – e.g. the kind that comes with a lot of electronic devices where the supply is built into the plug [you can use less than 12 volts; it will just spin slower and not move as much air], you can wire up the fan directly to that 12-volt supply instead of using the computer's supply.  You will, of course, need to find a way to join the wires [soldering iron, solder, and insulation tape are simple and effective].

Doing this on a water cooler might not be a good idea though (current requirements, possible grounding issues)

Comment: That's a nifty idea/observation :)

Answer (score 0):

You get a PSU that fits your needs.

The AMD FX 6300 is a 95W TDP processor The processor, motherboard and a single 4gb stick of ram goes over your power budget (I calculated based off [this site - and it suggests you'd use 152w at load](http://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator) - but looking at the TDP alone tells me something is off). This is *without* taking into account storage, and a video card, which the FX family would need

In theory you could power the fans off the motherboard (but once again, you're cutting it REALLY thin on how much power you have), and a cheap PSU is more likely to do strange things that close to their capasity.

That said, its somewhat unlikely its a 150w PSU. From memory, even the cheapest PSUs you commonly come across are 350W or more. Its also unlikely someone would throw an enthusiast grade processor and a very nice case and somehow throw in a grossly underpowered PSU.

If you're on a budget, there's seriously cheap powersupplys of over 250w around. If you're not, get a *good* powersupply with some headroom.

Comment: OP says, "I can't buy a new power supply". I'm... not sure why.

Comment: OP's also possibly wrong about his power supply capacity, and that PSU size can't even power his processor and motherboard with a single stick of ram. I would suggest that OP needs to get a series of hamsterwheels then, and a very small whip